# Add class to specific li item menu in function.php

Tags: menus

I wish to add a class to a specific item of my primary menu. I'm using this:

```
function hideMenuItem ( $atts, $item, $args ) {

    $commerce = get_field('ecommerce', 'option');
    if (!$commerce){
        $menu_items = array(566,567, 363, 364 );
        if (in_array($item->ID, $menu_items)) {
           $atts['class'] = 'hidden';
        }

        return $atts;
    }else{

        $menu_items = array(566,567);
        if (in_array($item->ID, $menu_items)) {
           $atts['class'] = 'visible';
        }

        return $atts;
    }
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'hideMenuItem', 10, 3 );
```

It's working only on the li link but I wish to apply it on the li.

Answer (score 1):

To add CSS classes to menu item `li`, use filter `nav_menu_css_class` ([codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/)).

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'hideMenuItem' , 15 , 4);

function hideMenuItem($classes, $item, $args, $depth) {

    $commerce = get_field('ecommerce', 'option');
    if ( !$commerce ) {
        $menu_items = array(566, 567, 363, 364 );
        if ( in_array($item->ID, $menu_items) ) {
           $classes[] = 'hidden';
        }
    } 
    else {
        $menu_items = array(566, 567);
        if ( in_array($item->ID, $menu_items) ) {
            $classes[] = 'visible';
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```